# Kafka communication using cloudera

Tags: apache-kafka, cloudera

On-prem--->HAProxy(AWS)--->Kafka(AWS). We can allow the external communication using advertised.listerers property and we can use the listeners for internal communication. If we are enabling both the settings,the communication is not happening properly. We are using 0.10.2 as Kafka version.

I believe we have  some setting to do through zookeeper to control the broker communication. How we can do it using cloudera?

Comment: Cloudera shouldn't matter, other than Cloudera Manager abstracts away editing the property files

Answer (score 0):

See https://rmoff.net/2018/08/02/kafka-listeners-explained/. You need to set up two listeners, one for the external IP through which your clients connect, one for the internal AWS network through which your brokers will communicate with each other.